# webpack error Cannot find module "run"

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack, webpack-2

I am getting following while creating the basic webpack project

Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "run"
    at webpackMissingModule (bootstrap 487ed85…:62)
    at Object.5 (bootstrap 487ed85…:62)
    at **webpack_require** (bootstrap 487ed85…:19)
    at bootstrap 487ed85…:62
    at bootstrap 487ed85…:62

my code is as follows
**webpack.config.js**

```
            var path = require('path');
            const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
            const webpack = require('webpack');

            module.exports = {
                entry: {
                    app: './src/scripts/index.js',
                    print: './src/scripts/print.js'
                },
                output: {
                    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
                    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/scripts/')
                },
                devtool: 'inline-source-map',
                devServer: {
                    contentBase: './dist',
                    hot: true,
                    port: 9000
                },
                plugins: [
                    //new CleanWebpackPlugin(['dist']),
                    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
                        title: 'Output Management',
                        filename: '../index.html',
                        template: 'src/index.html'
                    }),
                    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
                ],


                module: {
                    rules: [
                        {
                            test: /\.css$/,
                            use: [
                                'style-loader',
                                'css-loader'
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            };
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "webpack-site",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "webpack": "^3.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.16",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.4",
    "file-loader": "^0.11.2",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.29.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.18.2",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.11.0",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.18.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "watch": "webpack --watch",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --open",
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "author": "nabaraj",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

**index.js**

```
        import _ from 'lodash';
    import printMe from './print.js';
    import '../css/style.css';
    if (module.hot) {
      module.hot.accept('./print.js', function () {
        console.log('Accepting the updated printMe module!');
        printMe();
        document.body.removeChild(element);
        element = component(); // Re-render the "component" to update the click handler
        document.body.appendChild(element);
      })
    }

    function component() {
      var element = document.createElement('div');
      var btn = document.createElement('button');

      element.innerHTML = _.join(['Hello', 'webpack'], ' ');

      btn.innerHTML = 'Click me and check the console!';
      btn.onclick = printMe;

      element.appendChild(btn);

      return element;
    }

    document.body.appendChild(component());
```

Not able to find out the root cause. Also css is not getting added in head section.

Comment: Which npm command do you run to have this error: `build`, `watch` or `start`? (a few things aside: 1. You probably want to make separate webpack configs for dev and build, because hotreload and devserver are not necessary in build. 2. `print.js` is in webpack entry and also imported into your index.js. Is that what you want?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I am running npm run start command. print.js I wanted to create separate bundle file that's why added.